# The applyBindings() is too fast, called before Ajax request completes

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js

Please consider the following ViewModel snippet:

```
var id, given1, given2;

$.get("testSynUfGet.aspx", null, function (data) {
    id = data.id;
    given1 = data.given1;
    given2 = data.given2;
}, 'json');
//alert('here');
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(id, given1, given2));
```

It seems that my ajax call through `$.get` is too slow or the `ko.applyBindings()` is too fast. Either way, it seems that knockout can only properly bind if I uncomment the line `alert('here');`.

If I leave it commented, none of the controls get populated.

Any ideas, folks?

The only work around I could think of is to do `.applyBindings` as part of the function callback in `$.get` like this:

```
$.get("testSynUfGet.aspx", null, function (data) {
    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(data.id, data.given1, data.given2));
}, 'json');
```

Comment: Both answers are valid, depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Just wanting to revisit this, I believe my first way of thinking was still in the realm of synchronous programming.

The correct one is the second one - making the binding a part of the asynchronous process.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your workaround is the correct way to do things. This is your 'sucess' handler which is called when the data is returned and that is the correct point to then populate your view model and apply the bindings.

Comment: thanks Mark, - I'm marking this as answer for the time being (I'm relatively new in knockout).

Comment: I had a similar issue, although I had my data binding to the model correctly, I had some of my UI controls fail to bind properly in my template. (The accordion control was working, but datepickers inside teh accordion were not) The solution was to move the code that set my datepickers, etc into a function that was called after my 'success'.  Something else to keep an eye out for.  +1 Mark, your answer pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: This is the right answer - but I thought I'd add why...  - the $.ajax call is asynchronous, so it goes straight to the next line - the apply bindings.  By putting it in the callback, it gets called *after* the asynchronous process completes.  The best way to do it would be to put it in the .success() handler so that it only does it if it completes successfully.

Answer (score 8):

This workaround will only work as long as you have only one ajax call on the page. I think the right solution is to create your viewmodel first, with id, given1, and given2 being observables (initally empty). And then in the ajax callback, you change the value of those observables.

Answer (score 0):

More true way is execute your ajax call inside viewmodel object and populate his properties.