# Controlling Applybindings with knockout amd helpers

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, amd, knockout-amd-helpers

I'm using [Knockout AMD Helpers](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-amd-helpers) to load ViewModels, with the '[module binding](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-amd-helpers#module-binding)' feature.

Usually, when I need to load remote data I use a deferred object to ensure that ko.ApplyBindings is only called after all my data is available on the ViewModel.

I created a [sample jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7WKQd/19/) to illustrate my issue using a delayed ajax call:

```
self.initialize = function () {
                    self.name("This is a sample article");
                    self.getArticleTypes(self.articleTypes);
                };

self.getArticleTypes = function (observableArticleTypes) {
                    var fakeData = {
                        delay: 5
                    };
                    $.ajax({
                        async: true,
                        cache: false,
                        type: 'post',
                        url: '/echo/json/',
                        data: fakeData,
                        success: function (data) {
                            observableArticleTypes([{
                                id: 1,
                                articleType: 'Breaking News'
                            }, {
                                id: 2,
                                articleType: 'Weather'
                            }]);

                            console.log("Data loaded from server");

                        }
                    });
                };
```

How can I architect my code, using the AMD Helpers but delaying the ApplyBindings until all my data is ready on the ViewModel?

Comment: It would be great if someone could add the tag 'knockout-amd-helpers' to the question as I don't have enough reputation to do so

Comment: Seems to be the like this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427146/knockout-applybindings-is-too-fast?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this type of scenario, applyBindings will have already happened, so you would either want to just allow observable sections to update as data becomes available or control particular sections using the `if` or `with` or `template` bindings.

For example, you could wrap your area in a:

```
<div data-bind="if: articleTypes().length">
    ....
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. From a performance perspective is this the wrong way to go? My understanding is that bindings will be changing multiple times (as data gets loaded). I'm open to alternative ways to structure this.